# finding control limits without sample size

Tags: limits

**The problem**
A company sells bottles of 2L (2000 mL). The mean = 2000 mL, SD = 15 mL. 
Process required 2% (total) or less probability of over-filling / under-filling. What should the upper and lower limits be?

**My try of the answer is:**

If it requires a total of 2% (upper and lower). Than 1% is the upper limit. 1-0.11=.99
Next, z=2.326.
2.326=(x-2000)/15. x=2034.89 upper limit, and 1965.11 lower limit.

Is that the correct way to solve it? Or am I doing it all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly right, though there are some quirks in how you're writing it down. $1-0.11=.99$ is wrong; you probably meant $1-0.01=.99$. Also your limits are dimensionless numbers whereas they should be in millilitres. You write an equation for the upper limit, then appear to calculate both limits from it – of course the lower limit results from a slightly different equation; I guess you're aware of that, since you calculated it correctly. Apart from such niceties the calculation is correct.

Comment: Thank you joriki. You are correct on all the "mistakes" I did.